# Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, azure-ad-graph-api, onenote-api

Is onenote class notebook available through the Microsoft Graph API?

I'm trying to create a onenote class notebook and then add a list of students to it.

I have the documentation for adding a notebook

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/notes_post_notebooks

There is also a section for creating a section group

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/notebook_post_sectiongroups

Is a section group the same as a adding students?

I have also found this documentation, which references the OneNote API which is an older version I believe

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-classnotebook

Or is this possible through the Azure AD API?

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at https://blogs.office.com/2016/02/17/automate-onenote-class-notebook-creation-and-roster-changes-with-new-apis

The API above also allows adding of students after you have created class notebooks